# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: pages

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple crud app, I can add details and save to database, now I want to display these data.

Here is my solution for displaying these data

`PageListController` looks like this, just function to display data

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\PageList;


class PageListController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $pages = PagesList::all();

        return view('pages.index', compact('pages'));
    }
}
```

Here is `index.blade.php` on views

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['activePage' => 'table', 'titlePage' => __('Table List')])

@section('content')
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
            <h4 class="card-title ">Page list</h4>
            <p class="card-category">Here you can manage pages</p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-right">
              <a href="{{ route('pages.create') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add page</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead class=" text-primary">
                  <th>
                    ID
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Page Name
                  </th>
                  <th>
                  Articles
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Tags
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Status
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Action
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Prebid
                  </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  @foreach ($pages as $page)

                  <tr>
                      <td>
                        {{$page->id}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{$page->pagetitle}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{$page->articlelist}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                         {{{$contact->tags}}}
                      </td>
                      <td class="text-primary">
                        {{$page->status}}
                      </td>
                      <td class="td-actions">

                          <form action="" method="post">
                              <a rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success btn-link" href="" data-original-title="" title="">
                                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                              </a>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-link" data-original-title="" title="" onclick="confirm('{{ __("Are you sure you want to delete this user?") }}') ? this.parentElement.submit() : ''">
                                  <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                                  <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                              </button>
                          </form>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          {{$page->prebid}}
                      </td>

                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Now when I run the app I am getting the following error

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: pages (View: C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\royalad-dashboard\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)
```

Note: am so new to laravel .

> UPDATE

I have tried the most solution provided by fellas, but still; the same error, here is my repository [repo](https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PageListController.php)

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem is in your sidebar and in routing. In your sidebar you are trying to access Page List using `route('table')` and in your route file the route returns to the index page without the `pages` variable. And you are getting the error. Either change the sidebar like

```
<li class="nav-item{{ $activePage == 'table' ? ' active' : '' }}">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('pages.index') }}">
        <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
        <p>{{ __('Page List') }}</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

And if you want to use the `table` route then change in the route

```
Route::get('table-list', function () {
        $pages = App\PagesList::all();
        return view('pages.index',compact('pages');
    })->name('table');
```

Your compacting is just fine. don't need to change that.

Comment: Now I get this error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesList' not found`  :( it point to this `   $pages = PagesList::all();`

Comment: you have used `use App\PageList;` but used the model as `PagesList`. its a typo. just remove the  `s`. in controller `$pages = PageList::all();`

Comment: YOUR right, thanks and that solved my problem, U saved my ass, thx a lot brother, God bless ya.

Comment: be more careful. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

In your controller use:

```
return view('pages.index',['pages' => $pages]);
```

You are not binding pages the proper way, that is why when you try to access it in your blade, you get the error.

`view()` function takes the second parameter as the binding array. There you can pass the name and value of variables you would like to use in your blade.

In my experience, most of the time, I need more than one variables in my blade so I always make a data array and only pass that in the blade and then in blade I use the data array, like for your case lets say you wanted to pass a user object as well in your blade, I would do it like this:

```
$pages = PagesList::all();
$user = Auth::user();

$data = [
    'pages' => $pages,
    'user' => $user
];
return view('pages.index', ['data' => $data]);
```

Then in your blade you can use: `$data['pages']` and `$data['user']`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but still the same here is my repo https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PageListController.php, can you check what am I missing here?

Comment: Tested your solution , Now I get this error  `Undefined variable: data (View: C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\royalad-dashboard\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your web with the following code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('table-list', function () {
        return view('pages.index', ['pages' =>  $pages]);
    })->name('table');
```

Comment: I have tried this but still the same  here is my repo https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PageListController.php, can you check what am I missing here?

Comment: Updated my answer. check it out! @user9964622

Comment: I have changed as u requested now i get this error `Undefined variable: pages`  its pointing to this  `return view('pages.index', ['pages' =>  $pages]);` do I need add something in webb.app?

Comment: Means that the pages variable will be passed through your route(web) not with the controller so try declare the same function from the controller to route. just copy the codes to web inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

the error means that your pages variable is not being passed to your views.

Could you try this in your index function:

```
return view('pages.index')->with(compact('pages'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but still the same here is my repo https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PageListController.php, can you check what am I missing here?